# Error en API REST Node

Tags: nodejs

Intento hacer una petición de listar mis propiedades, pero cuando la realizo me da un **error 500** y me dice esto exactamente

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "mine" at path "_id" for
>   model "Property

El problema está en que la `ID` no la coge bien, pero no se por que, ya que no debería. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí está la petición que realizo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el método que busca las propiedades de un usuario por la ID de este.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí está el modelo "Property" con la referencia a User.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask], además puedes hacer el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla. Podrías complementar tu pregunta subiendo el código de lo que se realiza en Node? En específico la parte que está causando el problema. Saludos

Comment: Deberías añadir el código. Por lo que veo en la imagen que has subido, estas haciendo una consulta a bd usando "mine" como si fuera un id numérico

Comment: Mongoose es para conectarse a mongodb. _id hace referencia a un id. Se hace un cast al tipo de dato de _id y por el error que tiene está usando "mine" como un id que no cumple el tipo de dato. Por eso lo pongo como una respuesta.

Comment: @luismi tiene razón, verifica el orden en que estás ubicando tus middleware. Tal vez debas mover alguna cosa o cambiar la ruta del endpoint.

Comment: Una sugerencia, trata de evitar subir tu código como imágenes. No es bien recibido. A futuro hazlo mediante las herramientas que ofrece el sitio (snippets de código). Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

Express está "confundiendo" las rutas. Está procesando la ruta "/mine" con el controlador "/:id". Tan solo tienes que pasar el código del controlador con la ruta "/mine" encima, y debería funcionar.

Un saludo

Comment: Eso es lo que está sucediendo